# Can a template parameter be the type of an object that will be known at run-time?

Tags: c++, oop, templates, inheritance

Let's say I have a class `Grid` of 3 different kinds of squares each with different functionalities, all of which inherit from the parent class `Square`. I want to create a template like this where T1 is whatever the type of the current square (that my character is in) is. It could be any square in the Grid but that's only known when the function is called.

`template <typename T1, typename T2> void Grid::move(T1 current_square, T2 new_square){...}`

Comment: Why do you want to create a template? What is the benefit to you? This feels like a case where you would either have a specialization for each type of square or where you could simply use a `Square&` parameter. In either case, a template is not the right tool for the job. Can you give a more detailed statement of the purpose of this function while remaining abstract (not too many implementation details)?

Comment: @JaMiT I worked more on it and indeed, templates won't help. Essentially I want my function to access a member that belongs to only 2 of the 3 squares (so it's not in the parent class). If I just use `Square&` it'll give me a `Square has no member named..`error. I think I'll just implement a virtual function that will return the member I want from the 2 squares and do nothing on the 3rd type, although I was hoping for a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 1):

No, the template type has to be resolved at compile-time.  You'll want to make them both Square&, but you'll need some way for the object to tell you what kind of Square it is.

Comment: Yes and as far as I know there's no function that returns the type of a polymorphic object. I could do 3 if statements with dynamic casting to see what kind of square it is, but it seems like dodgy code. What if I had 20 types of squares instead of 3?

Comment: Well, this is what virtual functions are for.